# Using IntelliJ IDEA 12 for Flex Development

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I have been using Flex / Flash Builder for a number of years. The latest release of Flash Builder (4.7) seems to come with quite a few problems, the biggest of those being:

- Does not detect component `ID`s in MXML. For example, you cannot *Find Usages* of the ID of a component. Keeping the cursor on the ID of a component does not even *mark occurrences* of the ID. Instead, it *marks occurrences* of the actual `id` words in the MXML.
- **Extremely** slow.

I am seriously evaluating moving over to IntelliJ IDEA 12, especially after reading many experienced Flex devs raving about it and recommending it.

I tried it. It took me a while to get to terms with the new terminologies of the IDE (made easy by [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intellij-idea-vs-eclipse-terminology.html) doc and very helpful support personnel at JetBrains).

I was able to setup my (large) projects in IDEA with Adobe Flex 4.6 SDK and got it to compile fine. But I noticed many "errors" highlighted in my AS files which are all actually false alarms.

The ActionScript editor doesn't seem to recognise the objects defined in MXML. Apparently, this is a known bug in IDEA (tracked [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52598)). **And this bug has existed for more than 2 years!**

Quoting the JetBrains support personnel:

> I must admit that highlighting of ActionScript files which do not contain classes, but instead included in `mxml` as `<fx:Script source="some_file.as"/>` is probably the only weak part of IntelliJ IDEA code highlighting. False error highlighting will go away if you embed AS code inside CDATA of `<fx:Script/>` instead of referencing as external `*.as` file. Though I understand that this is not always desired.
>
> I'm afraid the fix won't go into 12 release because the release is very soon and the fix is too risky. Priority of the issue depends on votes and user feedback. So far we have only 2 votes (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52598) and as the fix is pretty complex we still haven't implemented it thinking that this is a rare use case. I hope to fix it in one of 12.x update releases.

My project is a huge one, with huge MXML files and even more huge AS code for each MXML. So, for organisation purposes, I need to logically split them into smaller files. So, merging the AS code with the MXML is not practical. The false error highlighting just drastically reduces the readability of the code. Also, it does not allow *Control / Command-clicking* component IDs in AS code to quickly navigate to the definition of the component in MXML (which, incidentally, is now broken in FB 4.7 as well, but worked well in FB 4.6).

This bug in IDEA is unfortunately a deal-breaker for me. But I am wondering how other Flex devs are able to overcome / work around this seemingly critical bug.

**It seems unbelievable to me that just 2 people have been affected by this bug**, especially with so many Flex devs recommending IDEA. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

All you Flex developers, I would appreciate your thoughts.

### UPDATE

This is in response to RIAStar's excellent and detailed answer. But it doesn't quite help me completely. Let me explain why and how I use `<fx:Script source>`. I am using Flex 4.x, with almost only Spark components.

- Suppose a brand new Flex project. The main application is an MXML file.
- In this MXML file, suppose I have a signup form.
- On editing the form (in each field), suppose I have to run validations and enable the *Submit* button only if the form is completely valid. This would mean I need to assign change event handlers to the form items. The event handlers is AS code.
- Suppose there is a *username* field which needs an *on-type* uniqueness check, by calling the server asynchronously. The server communication code is also AS code.
- And then of course, there is the *Submit* button handler, which is also AS code.

I usually put all the AS code in separate `.as` files and include it in the MXML using `<fx:Script source>`. This AS code is usually quite heavy, with a lot of functional and behavioural logic. Many times, based on user action, even the components in the MXML and layout of the elements is modified through this AS code.

If I understand you guys right, none of this event handler code should be in these MXML script files. So, where should it be? How do you guys do it? I am not sure how the Spark Skinning architecture has anything to do with this.

Comment: This is unrelated to your specific question; but are you using the 64-bit version of Flash Builder 4.7? In my own usage; it runs much smoother than Flash Builder 4.6.

Comment: Please explain why do you need source inclusion so much? 

I used including of code only once, when I wanted to add few methods to ChartBase, but had to write them in `.txt` file (because `.as` tried to be compiled separately with obvious fail) and include in several chart derivatives. 

I still remember this with  horror -  it is VERY dirty practice for oop.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: I am on OS X Mountain Lion, using FB 4.7 64 bit. There are quite a few complaints of slow performance on the Adobe Forums. I have tried the suggested workarounds of changing the Xms and Xmx properties in the FB.ini files. And using a fresh workspace created by FB 4.7 . Doesn't seem to have helped yet.

Comment: MXML files should only contain view specific behaviour to display data and send events to (View)Controllers/Mediators. You seem to mix in some business logic/application logic which does not seem to be the optimal way.

Comment: @user1875642 - I have updated my question to explain what I do with `<fx:Script source>`. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since I can't think of a gentle way of putting this, I'll just be blunt: I'm afraid the reason only two people think this is a critical bug, is that most seasoned Flex developers will agree that using `<fx:Script source="some_file.as"/>` is bad practice.
You effectively create two files that represent one class. From a readablity POV, which you seem concerned about, that's not a good move. One of these files (the .as file) is just a bunch of functions that cannot exist in their own right: they are tightly coupled to another file/class, but just looking at the .as file there is no way of knowing which class it is coupled to. Of course you can use some kind of naming convention to work around this, but in the end ActionScript/Flex is supposed te be used as a statically typed language, not a scripting language relying on mixins and naming conventions (don't get me wrong: I'm not saying scripting languages are bad practice; it's just not how ActionScript was conceived).

**So what are your alternatives?**
I suppose the main reason behind this construct is that you wish to separate MXML from ActionScript code, or in more abstract terms: separate the view from the logic. Fortunately this can be achieved in a few other, cleaner ways. Which solutions are available to you depends whether we're talking Flex 3 (or earlier) or Flex 4.
I realise that you may not have time to refactor your code to one of the proposed solutions, but I didn't want to leave you with just a "that's not good practice" answer.

### Flex 3 (mx)

**Code behind:** A lot of developers used the so-called "code behind" pattern to separate their logic from their view. You can find plenty of information on the topic by [Googling "flex code behind"](https://www.google.be/search?q=flex%20code%20behind). I don't need to repeat all that in here. I'm not much of a fan of the concept because it relies heavily on inheritance and the two resulting classes are still pretty tightly coupled, but at least we're talking two *classes*. If you design your architecture well, you may even be able to reuse some of your base classes.

**Compose model en controller:** I used to create a separate "presentation model" class and a "controller" class for each MXML view and then use it something like this:

```
<!--MyView.mxml-->
<mx:VBox>
    <m:MyModel id="model"/>
    <c:MyController model="{model}" view="{this}"/>
    ...
</mx:VBox>
```

MVC purists won't like this, but it worked pretty well for me in thencontext of Flex applications.
Later when **Direct Injection** supporting frameworks (like Parsley) made their appearance, I could use injection to wire all those classes instead of hard-wiring them like in this example.

**MVC frameworks:** My knowledge of this topic is sparse (because in my opinion Flex is a very decent MVC framework that requires no third-party additions, but that's another disussion), but in short: they can help you separate logic from view in a clean way.

### Flex 4 (Spark)

With Flex 4, the Spark skinning architecture was introduced, which allows for very nicely separated view and logic. You create a so-called 'host component' class in plain ActionScript, which contains all of the behavioural code, and a 'skin' class in MXML which defines the visual representation of the component. This makes designing reusable components very easy.

As per your request, here's a simplified example of how you might use Spark skinning to create your signup form.
Let's start with the skin class since it's easy to understand. It's just a form with some input fields. The `HostComponent` metadata tells the skin it's supposed to work together with the SignUp host component.

```
<!--SignUpSkin.mxml: the visual representation-->
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("net.riastar.view.SignUp")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:Form>
        <s:FormHeading label="Sign up"/>

        <s:FormItem label="User name">
            <s:TextInput id="userInput"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Password">
            <s:TextInput id="passwordInput" displayAsPassword="true"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:Button id="submitButton" label="Submit" 
                  enabled="{hostComponent.canSave}"/>
    </s:Form>

</s:Skin>
```

And now the host component in pure ActionScript. It has to extend `SkinnableComponent` to be able to use our skin (there's also `SkinnableContainer`which I've just recently explained in this question: [Flex mxml custom component - how to add uicomponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994928/flex-mxml-custom-component-how-to-add-uicomponents/13997864#13997864), but we won't be needing that here).

```
public class SignUp extends SkinnableComponent {

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var userInput:SkinnableTextBase;

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var passwordInput:SkinnableTextBase;

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var submitButton:IEventDispatcher;


    [Bindable]
    public var canSave:Boolean;


    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);

        switch (instance) {
            case userInput:
                userInput.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, 
                                           handleUserInputChange);
                break;
            case passwordInput:
                passwordInput.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, 
                                               handlePasswordInputChange);
                break;
            case submitButton:
                submitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                                              handleSubmitButtonClick);
        }
    }

    private function handleUserInputChange(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
        validateUsername(userInput.text);
    }

    ...

}
```

What's important here?
The variables marked as `SkinPart` will automatically be assigned the components with the same id that exist in the Skin you just created. For instance `<s:TextInput id="userInput"/>` will be injected into `public var userInput:SkinnableTextBase;`. Note that the type is different: `SkinnableTextBase` is the base class of `TextInput`; this allows us to create another skin with e.g. a `TextArea` instead of a `TextInput` and it'll work without touching the host component.
`partAdded()` is called whenever a SkinPart is added to the display list, so that's where we hook up our event listeners. In this example we're validating the username whenever its value changes.
When the validation is done, you can simply set the `canSave` property to `true` or `false`. The binding in the skin on this property will automatically update the Button's `enabled` property.

And to use both of these classes together:

```
<v:SignUp skinClass="net.riastar.skin.SignUpSkin"/>
```

Comment: Just something random though. Implementing IMXMLObject could clean up the delegation mechanism a bit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835854/flash-builder-4-6-code-behind-approach/10841887#10841887). And i just realized, that the class name in my example was poorly chosen.

Comment: @RIAstar - Thank you for your detailed answer. I have updated my question to include some more info. I would appreciate some pointers. Thanks!

Comment: So, in effect, the `<s:Application>` container would never contain non-custom components. For example, it would never contain `<s:Form>` or `<s:Button>` directly. Isn't this a very roundabout and complex way of building an application? I regularly use Spark Skinning and I am aware of all that you explained above. But I only use it when I want to change the appearance of a stock component or when I am building a completely custom component. I have never seen this Skinning approach used for building the base application structure. It seems very new to me.

Comment: @Anjan It's true that it brings a little more boiler-plate code (I use templates/snippets to get around that inconvenience; a feature available both in FB and IntelliJ Idea). But separation of concerns always does. And it gives you a great deal of flexibility in return. For instance, in the technical design phase of a project (yes, that early), I can create different skins to propose different solutions to the customer or project manager; all backed by the same behavioural code. I'm pretty confident that in the long run you gain more time than you loose initially by setting it up like this.

Comment: As for the reason why this technique isn't wide-spread: I think most developers will use an MVC framework of some kind (Robotlegs being the most popular right now) to create a similar separation of concerns. In that case the additional boiler-plate certainly isn't less. I'm certain many people will disagree with me, but in my opinion the Spark skinning architecture offers everything you need to do it without any third-party dependencies (which may become obsolete sooner than you bargained for).

Comment: @RIAstar This is a great answer, but it's not always possible to re-write/refactor very large application to use this techniques, which is the situation that I'm, also, in.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have become quite fond of using RobotLegs.

In my MXML views I try to keep all logic outside of the MXML and simply dispatch events out to the mediator. From there I can put code in the mediator to the heavier AS needed.