# Adding <fx:Declarations> via action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have an mxml page that has this tag:

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <mx:StringValidator id = "validator"
                            source = "{myTextInput}"
                            property = "text"
                            required = "true"
                            maxLength = "128"/>
<fx:Declarations>
```

I want to do the same in another page but build and add the validator dynamically using action script. I have this code for building the validator:

```
var lengthTextValidator:StringValidator  = new StringValidator();
lengthTextValidator.source = fieldTextInput;
lengthTextValidator.property = "text";
lengthTextValidator.required = true;
```

How can I finish the work and add the validator to the page? Thanks!

Comment: If `fieldTextInput` exists at the time this code is executed, there is nothing more to do; this will work just fine. The advantage of the mxml notation+binding is that you don't have to worry about whether the TextInput already exists or not: the binding will take care of that. (On a side note: there is no such thing as an "mxml page"; this is not HTML you're dealing with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a UIComponent as a child of another UIComponent you can use addChild():

```
myComponent.addChild(myOtherUIComponent);
```

However, a validator is not a UIComponent or DisplayObject.  It does not get added as a child to a page.  If you are just replacing the `fx:Declaration` piece of an MXML file with an ActionScript piece that does the same thing, then you don't have to do much more.

I would make the lengthTextValidator a public, or protected, instance variable on the component:

```
public var lengthTextValidator:StringValidator  = new StringValidator();
```

That means the variable will be use within the component.  Your original syntax without the public or private will either make a method specific variable that won't be accessible when the method is done executing or will put the variable in the internal namespace.

The rest of your code must go in a method.  For an ActionScript class; you can put it in a constructor.  Or for a MXML class you can put it in an initialize or creationComplete event handler.

```
lengthTextValidator.source = fieldTextInput;
lengthTextValidator.property = "text";
lengthTextValidator.required = true;
```

If you are putting the validator code in a separate class; then you'll have to import the class and create an instance of it:

```
import myPackage.MyClass;
public var myClass :MyClass = new MyClass();
```

Then you can access the validator by accessing the public variable on the component:

```
myClass.lengthTextValidator;
```

Finally; if you just want to move that snippet into an ActionScript file that is not a class; you can use the include directoive inside a fx:Script block:

```
<fx:Script><[[
 include "myASFile.as"
]]></fx:Script>
```

The last approach is unorthodox and not usually recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking into it!

Comment: Thanks for expanding on my thougths. I'm just so lazy these days that I quickly jot something down in a comment instead of writing a proper answer. And then you come in and do it for me ;) As for the 'include' tip: I've written [a case against it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046352/using-intellij-idea-12-for-flex-development/14047924#14047924) not so long ago, but +1 anyways ;)

Comment: @RIAstar I'm lazy these days too; but this was more interesting than the work I'm avoiding.  As I said regarding 'include' is that it is unorthodox and not recommended.